# Audio file tagging (read/write) library?

Tags: delphi, file, audio

TagLib seems like a good choice, but I don't use C++ and bindings for other languages are limited. Currently I use the ATL library, but it hasn't been maintained since 2005 and I'm having a hard time doing this myself. So I'm looking for another open source alternative that is actively developed. Do you know of one?

Comment: The library doesn't have to be a Pascal library though

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean id3 tags? The Jedi project has components to do that:
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=45786
Look for JvID3v1 and JvID3v2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Delphi component library called newac http://code.google.com/p/newac/ that has bindings for TagLib.

Comment: NewAC doesn't wrap TagLib.  It has Delphi implementations of parsers for ID3v1, ID3v2, APEv2, and Vorbis.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it personally, but it looks like [Audio::TagLib (in CPAN)](http://search.cpan.org/~dongxu/Audio-TagLib-1.43/lib/Audio/TagLib.pm) is a Perl interface / substitute for TagLib.